# Can I install a zip file without pom file to maven local repository

Tags: java, maven

I want to include a java project as dependency in my project, but the dependency doesn't has any pom file, so I want to know how I can depend on this file.

The project I want to depend on is the JTS3ServerMod (http://forum.teamspeak.com/threads/51286-JTS3ServerMod-Multifunction-TS3-Server-Bot-(Idle-Record-Away-Mute-Welcome-)) Plugin API.

Comment: Create a pom file for it and install it into your local cache via `mvn install:install-file ...` or better if you are using a repository manager install it there....

Comment: I did this, but in the IDE the classes can't be resolved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=JTS3ServerMod.jar -DgroupId=de.stefan1200 -DartifactId=stefan1200 -Dversion=6.4.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

This means that the dependency will be installed inside your repository, and will generate the pom file, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.stefan1200</groupId>
  <artifactId>stefan1200</artifactId>
  <version>6.4.0</version>
  <description>POM was created from install:install-file</description>
</project>
```

Repository path: `~\.m2\repository\de\stefan1200\stefan1200\6.4.0`

Comment: You must extract dependency *(jar)* and execute the previous command where you have the downloaded dependency

Comment: It's not a jar file, it is packaged in a zip file. I can't extract any jar file.

Comment: I tested it with the following zip file: http://www.stefan1200.de/downloads/JTS3ServerMod_6.4.0.zip inside of this file you have `JTS3ServerMod.jar` file, this file you must extract for example in `~/Downloads/` path

Comment: For plugin development I need the JTS3ServerMod\documents\plugin_sources\plugin_api_bin.zip in the zip you said.

Comment: No, in that case I think that you first need to convert the binary files to jar